# private members naming convention

Tags: .net, coding-style

In our project we use both VB.NET and C# code.

Now, Microsoft *seems* do not recommend using "_" or "m" prefixes for the private fields (like `_BackColor` for the `BackColor`).

From the other part, the used by Visual Studio "C# standard" to lowercase the private field can't be applyed in VB.NET code, because VB do not support distinguishing identifiers by case.

What do you think?

**PS.**
Studying a little bit more MS conventions I find out that Microsoft *have no* public recommendations of private fields naming, so we can use any of desired...

Comment: Correct. There are no public recommendations for how you name private fields because they're *private* by definition. No one else sees how you name those fields, so it doesn't matter. I use either `_` or `m_` because VB.NET is case-insensitive. I do the same in C# because I wish it were case-insensitive. There's absolutely nothing wrong with this, as long as you're *consistent* throughout your code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a standard is to promote consistency and understanding.

In this case because you have multiple languages I'd go with either "_" or "m" but make sure that you document **why** you've made this decision so that in 18 months time a new hire (or even you) doesn't look at the code and go "WTF?".

Comment: I'm not sure why you should have to document this if you've named *all* of your private fields this way. Consistency is the point here, and you've already mentioned that in your answer. I don't want to see comments in the source code about this; that's just noise. Prefixing variables with an underscore or an `m_` is a perfectly standard convention, and it takes 10 seconds for a newbie to figure out. No WTF necessary.

Comment: @Cody - I wasn't thinking about documenting it in the code, just in the company standards document (which should be no longer than a single sheet of A4). Why should you write it down? Because people do forget.

Comment: finally, what is better `_B`, `_b`, `mB` or `mB`? ) I'd select `_B` because if you'd have a Public "YShit", the developer should have to deal with `m...`

Comment: @serhio - if you really can't decide roll a 4 sided dice - they're all equally valid, but go with `_B` if that's what you prefer.

Comment: @ChrisF: I just think that the "m" prefix could sometimes change the meaning of the variable name...

Answer (score 1):

I usually name my private properties with camel case, or prefix them with a '_' and then continue with camel case, *depending on the language*.

```
private bool isReady;
private bool _isReady;
```

Prefixing with '_' does look cleaner in my opinion because it avoids using `this` when the parameters might be called the same.

```
class Person
{
    private string _name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

You should however try to hold on to **one** convention.

Comment: so, you have no standard, if you have two. As for me, I can't use the first, so you'd recommend the second?...

Comment: @serhio: I do but it depends which language I'm dealing with, in AS3 I usually go with the second while in C# I'm used to the first. I would indeed recommend you the second.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) to validate your code against inconsistencies.  StyleCop prefers the use of `this`, rather than prefixing members (as do I) for the following reason:

> By default, StyleCop disallows the use
>   of underscores, m_, etc., to mark
>   local class fields, in favor of the
>   ‘this.’ prefix. The advantage of using
>   ‘this.’ is that it applies equally to
>   all element types including methods,
>   properties, etc., and not just fields,
>   making all calls to class members
>   instantly recognizable, regardless of
>   which editor is being used to view the
>   code. Another advantage is that it
>   creates a quick, recognizable
>   differentiation between instance
>   members and static members, which will
>   not be prefixed.

For case-insensitive languages, use an agreed prefix.

Comment: this is not about parameters, this is about private fields. So have nothing with `this` (or `Me` in VB...) in VB I can't have both `private backColor` and `public BackColor`...

Comment: So, what do you name private fields in case-insensitive languages? You can't just camel-case the property names.

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with parameters. I'm saying you should not use any prefixes on private fields, and use camelcase, so call your field backColor in your case. Then use this when accessing the field inside your class.

Comment: You're missing the point. You can't call the field `backColor` because the property is named `BackColor`. The CLR doesn't specify that all compliant languages be case-sensitive. Your "rule"/"convention" is simply neither.

Comment: I take your point Cody, as long as there is consistency I don't think it matters, and a tool like StyleCop can help greatly. In which case I would favour using no prefixes in C#, and an agreed prefix in VB.NET.

Comment: @devdigital: "no prefixes in C#, and an agreed prefix in VB.NET." so the convention is not universal one. If tomorrow I'll add a project in C++, I probably should use an other convention?

Comment: Yes, as long as you're consistently inconsistent, you can't go wrong.

Comment: I think the propagation of languages would probably pose a greater cumbrance on the maintainability of the code base than the use or otherwise of prefixes on private fields.